# Probable number of missing records

Tags: probability

[Note: This is a duplicate of a post I made in Stack Overflow]

I am having difficulty grasping a probability assumption in a problem I am reviewing.

**Given:**

- each record in a dataset has a unique transaction id number (TXNID)
- The incremental change between TXNID is predictable based on the transaction time (the specific method is irrelevant to the problem)
- Because the incremental change is predictable, we can identify if a record is missing between two sequential TXNID.  Specifically, if the difference between two sequential TXNID is greater than the predicted incremental change, then at least one record is missing

  - The increment between two TXNID is always a whole number between 1 and 20 (inclusive)
  - Equal probability exists that any increment of 1 to 20 will occur

Where such a gap is identified, we wish to estimate the number missing of records.

**For example:**

```
    Previous TXNID: 100 (given)
    Current TXNID: 125 (given)
    Predicted increment: 5 (given)
    Actual increment: 25 (current - previous)
```

The actual increment is greater than the predicted increment so we know that at least one record is missing.

We also know that one missing record has a TXNID that is equal to the current TXNID - 5. The estimating records within the remaining gap is the focus of the problem.

```
   Remaining gap: 20 (actual increment - predicted increment)
```

What we wish to estimate is the number of missing records within the remaining gap.  In this example, the missing records may be comprised of a single record having an increment of 20, 20 records having increments of 1, or any relevant combination between these extremes.

```
    20 = 20 x 1
    ...
    20 = 1 x 20
```

The author proposes that because an equal probability exists that each TXNID increment is within 1 and 20, 5% (1/20) of the remaining gap is a realistic estimate for the number of missing records.

Having tested this in a very limited fashion, the assumption appears work; however, I am struggling to understand the logic that each scenario has an equal probability.

I agree that a single record has a 1/20 (5%) chance of having an increment of 20 (scenario 1 x 20).  But for the reverse scenario (20 x 1), shouldn't the probability compound?  Here, I not only require that the increment of a single record be 1 (5% probability), but also the next 19 records also be 1.  Therefore, it seems that the probability of 20 missing records existing within the remaining gap is significantly less (0.05 ^ 20 versus 0.05).

Am I over thinking this? Have I missed a point? Does applying 5% to the remaining gap make sense as a means to estimate the number of missing records?

Thanks

Andrew